# "Invalid gemspec in" and "Illformed requirement" whenever I create a new project in rails (cucumber issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Every time I create a new project I get the following errors:

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:for_testing adam$ rails new outsidein
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/specifications/cucumber-1.0.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["# 0.8.4"]

Invalid gemspec in [/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/specifications/cucumber-1.0.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["# 0.8.4"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/specifications/cucumber-1.0.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["# 0.8.4"]
```

I've updated cucumber and cucumber-rails but I get the errors all over the place. What do I do?

Comment: Can you post the output from "gem list" and "which rails" please.

Comment: @andywaite
gem list:  
    Invalid gemspec in [/Users/adamtal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/specifications/cucumber-1.0.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000102452b28> 0.8.4"]  

    *** LOCAL GEMS ***  

Invalid gemspec in [/Users/adamtal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/specifications/cucumber-1.0.4.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000102452b28> 0.8.4"]
abstract (1.0.0)
...
lots of gems!!!
...
ZenTest (4.5.0)
which rails

/Users/adamtal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/bin/rails

Comment: Not spacing correctly. Sorry about the appearance.

Comment: Can you post a link to the full output on http://pastie.org/, it would probably be useful to see all the Gems you have. Also, please include the contents of your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.

Comment: http://blog.rubygems.org/2011/08/31/shaving-the-yaml-yacc.html suggests that upgrading Rubygems may fix the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what this writeup wants me to do. I have the latest version of rubygems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber-rails 0.3.2 required cucumber > 0.8.0, but when bundler changed us from 0.10.2 to 1.04 it broke. Require an older cucumber like 0.10.2 and it will work

gem 'cucumber-rails', '0.3.2'
  gem 'cucumber', '0.10.2'

Comment: (our cucumber-rails version was also limited by our specified nokogiri version, fwiw)

Comment: (we're on rubygems 1.3.6.  rvm install rubygems 1.3.6; also fixes  ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex error )

Comment: This seems to have worked! Will need to test it out some more. However, will I be able to use the new version of cucumber with my current version of bundler at some point?

Answer (score 63):

You need to update to the latest version of Rubygems, but you may also need to remove any gems installed on the older version of Rubygems.

If you're using rvm with gemsets, this is quite easy:

```
$ rvm gemset empty
```

Now you can update Rubygems:

```
$ gem update --system
```

If you've lost bundler because it was installed in your gemset, install it in the global gemset so it's there for all your gemsets, for good:

```
$ rvm @global gem install bundler
```

Now you can reinstall all your gems in a nice clean gemset on the shiny new Rubygems:

```
$ bundle
```

Happy now?

Comment: Will this remove all my gemsets in the current ruby implementation? Also, "rvm gemset clean" didn't work. Did you mean "rvm gemset clear"? Thanks

Comment: I think it is `rvm gemset empty`.

Comment: yep `rvm gemset empty`. It'll blow away your gemset, but this is good. Rerun `bundle` to install fresh.

Comment: It's now `rvm all do gem install bundler`

Answer (score 9):

This issue is best described on RubyGems blog:

http://blog.rubygems.org/2011/08/31/shaving-the-yaml-yak.html

TL;DR: `gem update --system` and `gem update bundler`

RubyGems 1.8.10 solves this.

Comment: If the gem is already installed, the broken gemspec has already in. You can solve that by removing the gem and installing it again.

Answer (score 4):

See what helped me out:

```
$ gem update --system
...
$ bundle update
```

Notes:

1. I use Ruby 1.8.7-352.
2. Cucumber is visible to the Bundler via Gemfile so I can manage its version from there.

I think the key is updating rubygems.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I've already done this. I'm running the latest version of bundler. I even created a new gemset using ruby 192p180 with rails 3.0.10 and got this error right away when i did a bundle install having declared 'cucumber-rails' in my gemfile.

Comment: I'm just curious: did you run gem update --system ? I'm sure it's all gem(1) problem: they did some work on security issues.

Answer (score 4):

I had a lot of this kind of errors too. I just manually edited .gemspec files and changed `#<Syck::DefaultKey-blah-blah` to `=`. For vim the search and replace command is `%s/#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x.*>/=/`.

Answer (score 1):

I just pinned cucumber to 1.0.2, helps for the moment...

```
  gem 'cucumber', "1.0.2"
  gem 'cucumber-rails', "1.0.2"
```